# How to deal: my 'count' query does not get zero, when records not exist

Tags: sql, sqlite, view, record

I have a situation when it's needed to have a row of customer info (name, address, number etc.) and a count of cars he has. Each person are able to have any count of cars (car_name, VIN etc.)

And so i need to have a view with record info about customer and count of cars he has

**SQL query**

```
SELECT customer.id, customer.name, COUNT(car.id), customer.ipn, customer.address
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN car ON customer.id = car.customer_id
```

Everything OK for customers, that have cars, but for those, who not, bad, because they are not shown. I want to see zero, as well

**DATA SET**

TABLE 'Customer'

[image]

TABLE 'Car'

[image]

VIEW RESULT

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Join` with `Group By`

```
SELECT cu.id,cu.name,COUNT(cu.id) AS [COUNT],cu.ipn,cu.address,cu.number,cu.email
FROM Customer cu 
JOIN Car ca ON cu.id = ca.customer_id
GROUP BY cu.id,cu.name,cu.ipn,cu.address,cu.number,cu.email
```

Comment: @forpas I haven't checked the query, cos it looks too complex for me, but i tried the advise "Use Join with Group By". I wrote "GROUP BY customer.id" and it started to work properly

Comment: @forpas now i see that the answer has simple JOIN word. Ok. I'll edit it later when stackoverflow 'edit queue' will be free. Anyway i didnt know that it doesnt work for inner join